# Counting occurences of characters in a String using tail recursion

Tags: scala, tail-recursion

I have no clue how to count the occurrences of characters in a string using tail recursion in scala.

I need to run a program with input

```
times(explanation)
```

and the output is:

```
List((e,1), (x,1), (p,1), (l,1), (a,2), (n,2), (t,1), (i,1), (o,1))
```

I tried running RLE so far but the topic of tail recursion is new to me, so some steps/algorithm for doing so would be perfect

Comment: The output you need isn't RLE. Run-length encoding compact neighboured letters only. Your output just group and count how many elements are in input. What exactly you need?

Comment: It's clearly an assignment. So, what have you tried? A recursive solution breaks down the problem into sub-problems. What could be the subproblem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible Solutions:

A String is a list of characters.
Group them by identity which is (x => x), then count them.
Normally groupBy returns a Map which can by transformed to a list of tuples by toList.

**Code/ not reinventing the wheel**

```
def times(s: String) = s.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size).toList 
times: (s: String)List[(Char, Int)]
```

**Example**

```
times("explanation")
res1: List[(Char, Int)] = List((e,1), (x,1), (n,2), (t,1), (a,2), (i,1), (l,1), (p,1), (o,1))
```

**Code with tail recursion / reinvents the wheel/ please use not to cheat in the Coursera Scala Course**

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec

def myTimes(s: String) : List[(Char,Int)] = {

  @tailrec // comiler cheks if really tailrecursive
  def timesTail(chars: List[Char], res: List[(Char,Int)])  : List[(Char,Int)] = 
    chars match {
      case Nil => res      // we are done when there are no characters left
      case char :: rest => {
          // otherwise 
          val newCharCount = 
            res.
              find (_._1 == char). //check if we already have seen the character
              map{ case (c,count) => (c,count + 1)  }. // if yes, we raise take the old count and raise it by one
              getOrElse( (char,1) ) // otherwise we count one occurrence
          // here it gets recursive 
          timesTail(
                rest, // remaining Characters
                newCharCount :: res.filterNot(_._1 == char) // add the new count to list, remove old if present
          )
      }
    }
  // initial call with empty lsit to start the helper function  
  timesTail(s.toList,List())

}
```

Comment: You don't need the first `.toList`. `groupBy` works on Strings. Also, the ordering is different from the OP's list, but this may not matter

Comment: You could use `partition` to split `res` into a (possibly empty) list of the entry for `char` and the rest (same as your `res.filterNot`)  in one pass...

Comment: good idea with partition. But wanted to stay with the basics here. +1

Answer (score 0):

Efficient, this is not. But it is tail-recursive, and the output is in the same order as in the question, in case that matters. If this isn't an assignment then Andreas's `groupBy` solution is the better solution.

```
  def times(s: String) = {
    def timesRecurse(s: String, result: List[(Char, Int)]): List[(Char, Int)] = {
      if (s.isEmpty)
        result
      else {
        val c = s.head
        val i = result.indexWhere(_._1 == c)
        timesRecurse(s.tail,
           if (i == -1) 
              (c, 1) :: result
           else
             result updated (i, (c, result(i)._2 + 1)))
      }

    }
    timesRecurse(s, List[(Char, Int)]()).reverse
  }

  times("explanation")
  //> res0: List[(Char, Int)] = 
  // List((e,1), (x,1), (p,1), (l,1), (a,2), (n,2), (t, 1), (i,1), (o,1))
```