# Getting an error "constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type; found : (T1, T2) required: List[(Char, Int)]"

Tags: scala

I am new to Scala and working on a small assignment on Lists and Pattern Matching. The assignment is straight forward calculate the frequency of each unique character in a list and emit out a list of (Char,Int) tuples. I am getting the error on the line where I am trying to pattern match (`...case(cs.head, _)...`) to see if the current character has already been counted.

```
def times(chars: List[Char]): List[(Char, Int)] = {
    def calcCharFreq(c: Char, cs: List[Char], count: Int): (Char, Int) = {
        if(cs.isEmpty) (c, count)
        else
            if(c == cs.head) calcCharFreq(c, cs.tail, count+1)
            else calcCharFreq(c, cs.tail, count)
    }

    def calcFreq(cs: List[Char], pairs: List[(Char, Int)]): List[(Char, Int)] = {
        if(cs.isEmpty) pairs
        else{
            pairs match {
                case (cs.head, _) => calcFreq(cs.tail, pairs)
            }
            calcFreq(cs.tail, calcCharFreq(cs.head, cs.tail, 0) :: pairs)
        }
    }
    calcFreq(chars, Nil)
}
```

Thanks in advance
SK

Comment: `pairs: List[(Char, Int)]` is a List and you are matching it as a Tuple2.

Comment: Ah, the flurry of questions that comes when the Coursera course starts again. Not bothering with the honor code much? Another user thinks the same way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26502978/counting-occurences-of-characters-in-a-string-using-tail-recursion

Comment: @Paul last I know, you are not obligated in anyway to reply. You are welcome to sit on your high pedestal and stop patronizing.

Comment: I think I'll make my own decisions about whether to reply or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To actually check to see if you already have a tuple in `pairs` that matches your current char (`cs.head`), you want to replace the else clause containing the match in question with something like:

```
  if (pairs.exists(_._1 == cs.head)) {
    calcFreq(cs.tail, pairs)
  } else {
    calcFreq(cs.tail, calcCharFreq(cs.head, cs.tail, 1) :: pairs) // I noticed this needed to pass a 1, not a 0, for the initial count, or you would fail to count the first instance of the character...
  }
```

The match itself won't compile anyway, for the reasons given already by @tuxdna and @AlexeyRomanov.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. It worked. Although I don't understand yet the syntax `.. _._1 ..` I am sure in the coming weeks I will be able to wrap my head around this a bit more. Thanks again.

Comment: The first underscore represents the current pair being checked, the second is actually part of a field name, `_1`, which is the first field of the pair of two fields (ie. the key). A more verbose way of saying the same thing would be `pairs.exists( current => current._1 == cs.head )`.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't use `cs.head` in pattern matching like this. You need to assign it to a variable starting with a capital letter (lower-case variables in `case` create a *new* variable even if there is such an identifier in outer scope).
2. `(_, _)` is a pattern for (2-element) tuples, and `pairs` isn't a tuple. To match a list's head and tail, you write `case head :: tail`.

Combining, in this case you need

```
else {
  val C = cs.head
  pairs match { case C :: _ => ... }
}
```

Note that you need to handle other cases as well.